# Fastest subdirectory listing

Tags: vb.net, directory

I have an application where i want to get all subdirectories (first level) from a given path.
I use this code:

```
 Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\Folderlist")
 For Each d In di.EnumerateDirectories()
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString)
 Next
```

As you can see, i just need the name of the folder, not some object with all info.
Is there any way i can speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dirs() = Directory.GetDirectories(Application.StartupPath & "\Folderlist")
For Each dir In dirs
    Dim parent = Path.GetFileName(dir)
    Console.WriteLine(parent)
Next
```

- MSDN -
  [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

> Gets the names of subdirectories (including their paths) in the
>   specified directory.

[Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I think this is the solution i need, only, this returns the full folder path. Now i have to take a substring from the results. Maybe there is some way around this?